# Failed generated stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

This is the code

```
CREATE TABLE `church` (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `StudentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `semesterID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attendedWed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attendedFri` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attendedSabM` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attendedSabE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ChurchScore` double(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((((((`attendedWed` + `attendedFri`) + `attendedSabM`) + `attendedSabE`) * 100) / 60)) STORED
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is the error

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database. Executing: ALTER TABLE `citizenshipgroup3`.`church` 
>   CHANGE COLUMN `ChurchScore` `ChurchScore` DOUBLE(10,2) NULL DEFAULT
>   `attendedWed` ;
>
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near '`attendedWed`' at line 2 SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE
>   `citizenshipgroup3`.`church`  CHANGE COLUMN `ChurchScore`
>   `ChurchScore` DOUBLE(10,2) NULL DEFAULT `attendedWed`

Comment: What stored procedure, what alter statement?

Comment: `DEFAULT attendedWed` - I doubt that you can define default value of a column to be another column. **Edit**: Actually it is allowed but only for MySQL version >= 8.0.13 (specific patch indeed). Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: Do not understand @Madhur Bhaiya

Comment: so i should update workbench and it might work?

Comment: @MykeWolf Workbench is just a client interface. You need to update MySQL server to the latest version. But from your error message, I think you are not using MySQL, but MariaDB. I am not sure if MariaDB supports Expressions as Default Column value yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is fine.  The problem is that MySQL does not support generated columns until 5.7.  You are presumably using an earlier version.

Probably the simplest solution is to use a view for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears at the time of `ALTER TABLE`, when you are trying to modify the column `ChurchScore` setting the `DEFAULT` value to an expression involving another Column `attendedWed`.

Also, your error message seems to be originating from MariaDB, not MySQL.

From [Mariadb Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/):

> From MariaDB 10.2.1 you can use most functions in DEFAULT. Expressions
>   should have parentheses around them. If you use a non deterministic
>   function in DEFAULT then all inserts to the table will be replicated
>   in row mode. You can even refer to earlier columns in the DEFAULT
>   expression:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (a int DEFAULT (1+1), b int DEFAULT (a+1));
> CREATE TABLE t2 (a bigint primary key DEFAULT UUID_SHORT());
> ```

So you need to ensure couple of things:

1. Upgrade your MariaDB version to 10.2.1 and above. Preferably, upgrade to current latest version (it is 10.3+ right now).
2. You need to use parentheses around the expression specified in the `DEFAULT` clause.

So the `ALTER TABLE` statement would look like:

```
ALTER TABLE `citizenshipgroup3`.`church` 
CHANGE COLUMN `ChurchScore` `ChurchScore` DOUBLE(10,2) NULL 
DEFAULT (attendedWed) ;
```